# Why is my regular font garbled but \emph and \textbf fine?

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I'm trying to format a document following my organization's style guide. I'm using `XeLaTeX` for the font flexibility. I made a minimal document

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{xltxtra} %% For XeTeX font commands
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Frutiger LT Std 45 Light}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot, margin = 0.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
Main font, no styling, \emph{with emphasis}, \textbf{and bolded}.
\end{document}
```

and the `\emph{}` and `\textbf{}` text comes out just fine, but the rest is garbled:

[image: garbled]

#### The part where it's probably my fault

I needed to use this font in some graphs generated in R. I have several fonts in the Frutiger family installed on my (Windows) machine, and they're OTF fonts. To get the font to work in R, I need to use the `extrafont` package, which only works with TTF fonts. So I fed `Frutiger LT Std 45 Light` into an online OTF to TTF converter, and reinstalled the TTF version. It works great for my R figures, but maybe that has something to do with my `XeTeX` font problems. If I run the above example with `\setmainfont{Frutiger LT Std 55 Roman}` instead of using the TTF-converted light face, nothing is garbled, it's just too heavy.

My compilation report for the example above says 0 Errors, 0 Warnings; the `.log` file reports

```
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'FrutigerLTStd45Light(0)' created for font 'Frutiger LT Std 45
. Light' with options [].
. 
. This font family consists of the following shapes:
. 
. * 'normal' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Frutiger LT Std 45 Light/ICU:script=latn;language=DFLT;"
. 
. * 'bold' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Frutiger LT Std 45 Light/B/ICU:script=latn;language=DFLT;"
. 
. * 'italic' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Frutiger LT Std 45 Light/I/ICU:script=latn;language=DFLT;"
. 
. * 'bold italic' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Frutiger LT Std 45 Light/BI/ICU:script=latn;language=DFLT;"
.................................................
```

Any help/pointers?

Comment: If you are using XeTeX < 0.9998 on Linux or Windows, make sure you don’t have several different copies of the font installed, as this is known to cause issues like that.

Comment: @KhaledHosny That was the issue. I updated XeTeX and now everything is working. If you'll post as an answer I'll accept. Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56739/729, so I think we should just mark it as such.

Comment: Which is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35090/729 :)